# Canceled ajax action after clicking on link

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm quite new with jquery but I wanted to add a quick preview of notes for users after they move mouse on the title of the note. But also, after they click on it I wanted them to edit the note. So I have two separate actions (in php )- for clicking and editing I have **getNote** and for quick preview I have **fastNote**. They work just fine, problem is with the jquery code - everything is great but after I click on link to edit the note and I went back the preview is not working anymore. Here is the jquery code:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $(".note").mousemove(function (e) {
       link = $(this).attr('href');
       link = link.replace("getNote","fastNote");
       $(this).attr('href',link);
       $.ajax( {
        type: "GET",
        url: link,
        success: function(result) {
           $("#news2").html( result ) ;
           put_preview(e) ;
        }
      });
   }); 
    $(".note").click( function() {
        link = link.replace("fastNote","getNote");
        $(this).attr('href',link); 
    });   

    $(".note").mouseout( function() {
     $("#news2").css('display','none');
    }) ;

    function put_preview(e) {
        $("#news2").html("<b>Notatka: </b><br />" + $("#news2").html());
        $("#news2").css('background-color','yellow');
        $("#news2").css('padding-top','5px');
        $("#news2").css('text-align','center');
        $("#news2").css('border','4px dotted blue');
        $("#news2").css('width','400px');
        $('#news2').css('position','absolute');
        $('#news2').css({'top': e.pageY - 20, left: e.pageX + 20});
        $("#news2").show();
    }

});
```

and I don't have any idea why it stops working once it's clicked.

Comment: Is the element selected by `.note` replaced when the user edits the note? In that case attach the click handler to a parent with `$(parentselector).on( 'click', '.note', function() { ... } );` so that it will persist, but only will work on `.note`'s

Comment: Provide a minimal jsfiddle which reproduce your issue. BTW, you should seriously refactorising your code

Comment: what do You mean by replaced? It's value is being changed, but everything else is the same. In php code I get the note from database, it still has the same class and so on. Basically - only the value changes.

Comment: @roasted - I have no idea how to put it on fiddle because it's quite complicated. I can give You the link to my site ( few things are in polish, but I think You will get what You need :D ) and You can add the note there. testdomain.fii.me